# PreInitialisation to initialisation error in Minecraft Forge

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I was making a mod and tried to add crafting recipies.
When I tried to launch it, it crashed and left a report. 
Can someone please tell me what I need to do to fix this?

> ---- Minecraft Crash Report ---- // Quite honestly, I wouldn't worry myself about that.
>
> Time: 19/04/16 20:25 Description: Initializing game
>
> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   5     at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)  at
>   net.minecraft.item.crafting.CraftingManager.addRecipe(CraftingManager.java:232)
>     at
>   cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry.addShapedRecipe(GameRegistry.java:250)
>     at
>   cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry.addShapedRecipe(GameRegistry.java:250) at cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry.addRecipe(GameRegistry.java:245) at com.Abhijith.Main.CraftingManager.addCraftingRec(CraftingManager.java:18) at com.Abhijith.Main.CraftingManager.MainRegistry(CraftingManager.java:13) at com.Abhijith.Main.MainRegistry.Preload(MainRegistry.java:23) at 
>   A lot of unneeeded lines follow...

here is my crafting manager

```
public class CraftingManager {
    public static void MainRegistry(){
        addCraftingRec();
        addSmeltingRec();
    }
    public static void addCraftingRec(){
        //Shaped
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(MBlocks.DiaSlab, 3), new Object[]{" "," ","XXX",'X', Blocks.diamond_block});
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(MItems.oStick, 1), new Object[]{" X "," X ", 'X', Blocks.obsidian});
        //Shapeless
    }
    public static void addSmeltingRec(){
        GameRegistry.addSmelting(Blocks.coal_block, new ItemStack(Blocks.obsidian, 1), 20.0f);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
String index out of range: 5 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source) at 
net.minecraft.item.crafting.CraftingManager.addRecipe(CraftingManager.java:232) at
```

`StringIndexOutOfBounds` means: if you have a string that has a length of 4, and try to access position 5, it does not exist, and you get this problem.

"hello" > length 5
h 0
e 1
l 2
l 3
o 4

it has 5 elements. But if you try to access it at 5, "hello".charAt(5) you'll get an string index out of bounds, because index 5 does not exist.

You probaly defined your recipe wrong.

So check your recipe in `CraftingManager.java:232`<-- line number

and check your documentation.

Without code, I can't help you.

**EDIT**

From the comments:

> DiaSlab, 3), new Object[]{" "," ","XXX" those strings before the XXX need to be   >equal lenth. Make them 3 spaces.

Comment: `DiaSlab, 3), new Object[]{" "," ","XXX"` those strings before the XXX need to be equal lenth. Make them 3 spaces.

Comment: If an answer helps mark it with the green checkmark and consider upvoting it